# Grails Hiberante

Tags: hibernate, grails

There are three domain objects .Person has multiple associations and associations has multiple transactions.

```
class Person implements Serializable{
 static hasMany = [associations: Association]
    static mappedBy = [associations: 'personId'] 
}
class Association implements Serializable{
 static hasMany = [transactions: Transaction]
    static mappedBy = [transactions: 'association']
}
class Transaction implements Serializable{
 .....
}
Person has multiple Associations and Associations has multiple Transactions

def personsList = [] 

def personList= []

def p = Person.createCriteria()

personList= p.listDistinct {

 order('personName','asc')

 eq("personType", "A")

 eq("statusFlag", "A")

 associations {

       order('legalName', 'asc')
         transactions {
             isNull('remittance_trx_id')
          isNull('cancelDate')
        between('paymentDate', flow.startDate, flow.endDate)
         or {
           eq('ufPayStatus', "AT")
           eq('ufPayStatus', "RT")
        }
        gt('ufBaseFee', 0.00)
        }
    }
    }
```

After getting list of results when I am trying iterate transaction object,It is executing multiple database queries for each association id.How could I avoid this scenario? This is happening after migrating latest version.It impacts performance a lot and getting timeout exception also.

personList{person ->

```
person.associations.each {association ->

     association.transactions.each {transaction ->

          BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(transaction.ufBaseFee)

             personTotal= personTotal.add(c)

  }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing here is the N+1 select issue with Lazy loaded collections. You may want to investigate using [eager fetching](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/fetchMode.html) for your collections.

```
class Person implements Serializable{
 static hasMany = [associations: Association]
 static mappedBy = [associations: 'personId'] 
 static fetchMode = [associations: 'eager']   
}
class Association implements Serializable{
 static hasMany = [transactions: Transaction]
 static mappedBy = [transactions: 'association']
 static fetchMode = [transactions: 'eager']   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a common issue in Grails.  [Burt Beckwith](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) gave a talk on it.

One solution is to get rid of your `hasMany` and `belongsTo` associations similar to what [this site](https://mrpaulwoods.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/implementing-burt-beckwiths-gorm-performance-no-collections/) describes.